# {$\frac{1}{x}$} , $0<x\leq1$ in terms of {$x$}, $x\geq 1$, {$x$} is fractional part of $x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, real-numbers, fractional-part

$f(x)$ $=$ {$\frac{1}{x}$}, $0<x\leq1$ where {$x$} denotes the fractional part of $x$.

$g(x) =$ {$x$}, $x\geq 1$

I want an expression for $f(x)$ in terms of x and $g(x)$.

My try-

If $x\in \mathbb{Z} , x\geq 1$ , g(x)={x}=0

f(x)={$\frac{1}{x}$}=$\frac{1}{x}$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+g(x)$$
What happens when x is a fraction?
Jacobi theta function $\theta(x)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi x}$ This function satisfies the functional equation $\theta(\frac{1}{x})=\sqrt{x}\theta(x)$. I want a similar functional equation of f(x) in terms of g(x)

Comment: Why do you think such an expression exists? What have you tried?

Comment: From where have you taken this problem?

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki I think there exists some function h(x) such that f(x)= h(x)*g(x) where * is a binary composition

Comment: @Forester I have taken it from number theory by edwards

Comment: @SHEKHARSUMAN What do you mean by "binary composition"?

Comment: @5xum Basically i mean +,-,×,÷

Comment: @SHEKHARSUMAN In that case, you can define $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$, and you then have $f(x) = h(x) + g(x)$. Or, you can define $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$, and you have $f(x)=h(x) - g(x)$.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki I have edited my try in the question.

Comment: Your question does not makes sense, you can't have at the same time $0<x<1$ and $x>1$ !!!

Comment: @Yves Daoust When $0<x\leq 1$ ,$\frac{1}{x}\geq 1$ so {$\frac{1}{x}$} is well defined

Comment: This is *not* what you wrote ! Fix your text. By the way, I answered for all $x>0$.

Comment: Just checking: is the answer $f(x)=g(1/x)$ acceptable? Maybe it is all a lot simpler than you've made it look?

Answer (score 2):

There is no expression for $f$ solely in terms of $g(x)$.

Proof:

Take $x_1 = 2, x_2=3$. Then, $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$, but $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$.

---

Intuitive explanation: an expression "in terms of $g(x)$" is an expression that only depends on the value of $g(x)$ and does not directly depend on the value of $x$. Therefore, the expression, whatever it is, will have the same value for $x_1$ and $x_2$. But since $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$, the expression cannot possibly capture both values, $f(x_1)$ *and* $f(x_2)$.

---

Rigorous explanaiton: An expression of $f$ in terms of $g(x)$ is, mathematically speaking, a function $h$ such that $f(x)=h(g(x))$.

Assuming that such a function $h$ exists, however, brings us to a contradiction, since any such function means that

$$f(x_1)=h(g(x_1))=h(g(x_2))=f(x_2)$$ which is a contradiction, because we know that $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$.

---

An expression "in terms of $g(x)$ **and** $x$", on the other hand, trivally always exists, since $f(x)$ itself is already an expression in terms of $x$.

Comment: I am talking about f(x)= h(x)*g(x), where * is a binary composition.

Comment: @SHEKHARSUMAN Then take $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and you are done.

Comment: See my answer. I am searching for an expression of this kind

Comment: @SHEKHARSUMAN  But the expression $\frac1x + g(x)$ is **not an expression in terms of $g(x)$**. The expression depends on $x$, as well as $g(x)$.

Comment: Exactly. This is my question. Any expression which depends on x and on g(x)

Comment: @SHEKHARSUMAN The expression $\left\{\frac1x\right\}$ depends on $x$ and (trivially) $g(x)$.

Comment: You know what i need.

Comment: @SHEKHARSUMAN No, I do not, and I am not joking here. If you want an expression that contains $g(x)$, then $g(x) + \left\{\frac1x\right\} - g(x)$ is one such expression. But honest to god, I have no idea what it is you are asking me to do.

Comment: @SHEKHARSUMAN I mean, for $x>1$, you have $f(x)=\frac1x$. I don't understand what you want to achieve further than that, it's a nice simple expression...

Comment: Jacobi theta function $\theta(x)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi x}$ This function satisfies the functional equation $\theta(\frac{1}{x})=\sqrt{x}\theta(x)$. I want a similar functional equation of f(x) in terms of g(x)

Comment: @SHEKHARSUMAN But... why? And why do you think it exists? And what's wrong with the expression $f(x)=\frac1x$? Is it no simple enough for you?

Comment: $x\geq 1$ was the domain for g(x) and $0<x\leq 1$ is the domain for f(x). Sorry for the misprint

Comment: @SHEKHARSUMAN The thing is that knowing the value of $g(x)$ will tell you *absolutely nothing* about the value of $f(x)$. What's worse, for every pair of values $y_1, y_2\in[0,1)$, you can find some $x$ such that $f(x)=y_1$ and $g(x)=y_2$.

Comment: @SHEKHARSUMAN If the domains of $f$ and $g$ are **disjoint**, how can you **possibly** express one function in terms of the other?!

Comment: Sorry I have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>1$,

$$\left\{\frac1x\right\}=\frac1x$$ and you are asking for $\left\{\frac1x\right\}$ as an expression involving $\{x\}$ and $x$ as a rational expression. I just wrote it above. Knowing $\{x\}$ is of no help.

For $0\le x<1$,

$$\{x\}=x$$ and you are in fact asking for $\left\{\frac1x\right\}$ as an expression involving $x$ alone as a rational expression. This is not possible due to the discontinuities in this function.

Comment: No. When x<1 I am asking for {$\frac{1}{x}$} as an expression involving x and {x}

Comment: @SHEKHARSUMAN: how can you be so blind ? When $x<1$, $x$ and $\{x\}$ are the same thing !

Comment: Ok i got it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=\left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}$ and $g(x)=\{x\}$, then $f(x)=g(\frac{1}{x})$, i.e. $f=g\circ h$ where $h(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Perhaps this is what the author of the problem had in mind, and you have been overthinking it?